# How to run a background procedure while constantly checking for input - threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, concurrency, python-multithreading

I have small server and client Python scripts where the client sends a string and the server responds with the reverse. When the client enters a quit string, the client exits and then the server exits.

I want the server's "receive, reverse, send" procedure running in the background while the program is constantly checking stdin for a quit string.

I've tried using `threading` but because of the blocking that many socket calls cause it wouldn't work properly.

Just so you can get an idea of what I've already done.

*server.py*:

```
import socket
from time import sleep

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1",12346))
sock.listen(3)
print "Waiting on connection"
conn = sock.accept() 
print "Client connected"

while True:
    m = conn[0].recv(4096)
    if m == "exit":
        sleep(1)
        break
    else:
        conn[0].send(m[::-1])

sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
sock.close()
```

*client.py*:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(("127.0.0.1",12346))

while True:
    s = raw_input("message: ")
    sock.send(s)

    if s == "exit":
        print "Quitting"
        break

    print sock.recv(4096)

sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
sock.close()
```

Comment: "receive, reverse, send" looks like taking a very short time, in my opinion, why would you like to make it run in the background?

Comment: Because I can't see any way to have "receive, reverse, send" and "get user input" in the same process because ``raw_input()`` blocks until it receives input which interrupts the flow of packets.

I have two ideas which I don't want to put into action:
Give the client the ability to kill the server, or limit how long ``raw_input()`` blocks for (a timeout)

Comment: I don't understand. So what you want is to combine the two scripts "server.py" and "client.py" into a single script and just run that one script? Or do you just want to run "server.py" in the background (in Unix it can be done using `python server.py &`)?

Comment: I want the server to be able to send and receive packets while at the same time checking for user input

Comment: Why would you like to do that? If there is only one client, the client will be waiting for the server to return the result anyway and won't send any more input to server, right? Probably you want the server to be able to handle multiple clients instead?

Comment: You want the server to quit when the person on the server console types 'quit' on stdin? And this is separate from the 'exit' the client can send? And you want the server to poll for data on stdin, rather than blocking in another thread?

Comment: @usmcs Yeah. In my ideal design the client won't be able to send an exit signal to the server; the only way to quit the server is from its own terminal instance.

While it's checking stdin for this quit signal, I want to be able to smoothly handle client connections, disconnections and packet processing.

Do you get me?

Comment: @lightandlight I think so, but I have two more clarifying questions: Will you have anything on stdin other than the quit command and does it have to be stdin or can it be a signal like ^C with a graceful exit?

Comment: @usmcs Ultimately I'd like to have multiple server-side commands other than quit, but for now I don't need any.

Comment: I see, I didn't notice that by "stdin" it should mean the "stdin" of the server terminal. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you want the server process to be able to handle the client while in the same time receiving input from the server's `stdin`, you can just put the whole current server code in a `Thread`, then wait input from `stdin`.

```
import socket
from time import sleep
import threading

def process():
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind(("127.0.0.1",12346))
    sock.listen(3)
    print "Waiting on connection"
    conn = sock.accept()
    print "Client connected"

    while True:
        m = conn[0].recv(4096)
        conn[0].send(m[::-1])

    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    sock.close()

thread = threading.Thread(target=process)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
while True:
    exit_signal = raw_input('Type "exit" anytime to stop server\n')
    if exit_signal == 'exit':
        break
```

and you can remove the "exit" checking in client.

In this code, the server will be doing nothing after the client disconnect, though, it will just wait for "exit" to be typed in the `stdin`. You might want to extend the code to make the server able to accept new clients, since you don't want the client to have the ability to close the server. In that case, you can put another `while` loop from `conn = sock.accept()` to `sock.close()`.

And as @usmcs suggested, if you don't have any other command to be sent to the server, it will be better if you use CTRL-C (`KeyboardInterrupt`) instead, so you don't need the thread, while it can still end the server gracefully (meaning no error due to the CTRL-C is reported) with this code:

```
import socket
from time import sleep
import threading

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1",12346))
sock.listen(3)
print "Waiting on connection"
conn = sock.accept()
print "Client connected"

while True:
    try:
        m = conn[0].recv(4096)
        conn[0].send(m[::-1])
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

sock.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I envisioned.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of non-blocking socket receiving. In case of no-data to receive socket will throw an exception.

```
import sys
import socket
import fcntl, os
import errno
from time import sleep

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',9999))
fcntl.fcntl(s, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)

while True:
    try:
        msg = s.recv(4096)
    except socket.error, e:
        err = e.args[0]
        if err == errno.EAGAIN or err == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            sleep(1)
            print 'No data available'
            continue
        else:
            # a "real" error occurred
            print e
            sys.exit(1)
    else:
        # got a message, do something :)
```

Here is an example of non-blocking stdin read:

```
import sys
import select

# If there's input ready, do something, else do something
# else. Note timeout is zero so select won't block at all.
while sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if line:
    something(line)
  else: # an empty line means stdin has been closed
    print('eof')
    exit(0)
else:
  something_else()
```

Basically, you want to combine them and may be add some timeout to force reading stdin on a regular basis in case of many connections.

Answer (score 1):

I took a gist I had previously published for building a pre-forked JSON-RPC Server in Python and modified the code to solve this problem. Gist Here: https://gist.github.com/matthewstory/4547282

```
$ python server.py localhost 9999 5
exit
$
```

Looking more into why this works. The main fork spawns `N` many forks (in the example above `5`), each of which goes into an accept loop:

```
# simple pre-fork server, fork before accept
for i in range(int(argv[2])):
    # fork our current process
    pid = os.fork()

    # if we are the child fork ...
    if 0 == pid:
        # die without unhandled exception
        for signum in ( signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM, ):
            signal.signal(signum, _gogentle)

        # under the hood, this calls `socket.accept`
        s.serve_forever()
        os._exit(0)

    # if we are the papa fork
    else:
        _PIDS.append(pid)
```

These child forks will handle any incoming requests to `localhost:9999`. The main fork then drops into a select/waitpid combo loop:

```
# setup signal relaying for INT and TERM
for signum in ( signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM, ):
    signal.signal(signum, _kronos)

# wait on the kids
while len(_PIDS):
    # 1s timeout here means we're checking for exiting children at most
    # 1x per second, prevents a busy loop
    reads, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 1)
    if sys.stdin in reads:
        # blocking, read 1 line
        cmd = sys.stdin.readline()
        # kill ourselves ... kronos will propegate
        if cmd.strip() == 'exit':
            os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)

    # check for exited children, non-blocking
    while True:
        pid, rc = os.waitpid(-1, os.WNOHANG)
        if not pid:
            break
        _PIDS.remove(pid)
```

The `select` will either indicate that `stdin` is ready for reading, in which case we will read 1 line from stdin, or it will timeout after at most `1s`, in which case it will fall-through directly to our check for any exited children (using `os.waitpid` with the `WNOHANG` flag).